# My Player won't take damage from the enemy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I went through the bolt tutorial but my Player wont take damage when colliding with the enemy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjkXk.png)

Here is the player touching it but not taking damage, Please help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o9Dm.png)

Comment: Can you add a picture of Player's inspector?